# Raid 5 verifying

Tags: raid, raid5

Good  day every one,
i all ready read this [RAID 5 detects write errors?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309980/raid-5-detects-write-errors)
I have raid 5 on "3 ware" controller i want to ask:
- do i need run from time to time verify schedule or i can use only smart-tests ?
- how often do you run first or second ?
- Did i understand right that verify would check hardware errors and RAID array consistency? 
- Should i use AutoVerify option ?
Please tell me if i wrong in it.

Comment: I've got an easier answer, don't use R5, it's 2014, I'm imagining your disks are 1TB or larger too? if so REALLY don't use R5.

Comment: yes, thank for your advice i know that i can use a R10 instead but, now i have R5 and have such questions. Would be glad if you can help me

Comment: You normally do not need to run tests on the drive to ensure it works. If the array encounters an error, the controller takes care of it (by pulling it out of the array) on its own. That said, you'll regret using R5.

Answer (score 0):

The 3ware controller should automatically detect errors and toss out disks that aren't up to snuff. If I know one thing about 3ware, it will make a nice soothing audible tone to let you know that it lost a disk.

If you need to check smart data, use smartctl in this fashion:

```
smartctl -i /dev/twe0 -d 3ware,0
```

You may need to use twa instead of twe. The 0 after 3ware identifies the port you are checking, and the 0 after twe identifies the controller number. Sometimes you can catch issues this way before a disk goes bad, or if a disk is failing and the controller doesn't throw it out for some reason.